# bash, cat, awk or something to parse a little list

Tags: bash, list, parsing, awk

I'm not a programmer, but now I have to automate some work.

I have a little list of usernames and resolutions, it looks like

```
username1 resolution1
username1 resolution2
username2 resolution3
```

and so on.

What I want is to loop through those lines, marking the usernames as one variable and geometry as another var and then launch something like

```
sudo -u $1 some_bin --geometry $2
```

for each line.

I know about cat, awk, but still have no idea how to use it :) In fact, I know a little, but I just can't make it work properly. I tried to go through arrays, but no help. I tried using "some_bin" inside awk - same result.
Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
while read username resolution
do 
    sudo -u "$username" some_bin --geometry "$resolution"
done < input_file
```

Comment: Awww damn, that's just great!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use heredocs:

```
while read username resolution; do 
    sudo -u $username some_bin --geometry $resolution
done <<EOF
  username1 resolution1
  username1 resolution2
  username2 resolution3
EOF
```